# Bars are too short, not visible anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqplot

so I have this chart with jqplot

[image: jqplot]

if you look carefully enough you can see that under 4 and 5 there is actually data to be displayed but the bars are too short for the number label to show. I have hover text but the bar is also too small for the mouse to register. Under 3 there is actually another bar in between the red and green but it's also too small to be displayed.

what can I do in this case? any suggestions?

I have a couple of ideas but dunno how to implement:

- display the number label next/on top of each bar only when the bar is a certain percentage smaller than the tallest one.
- have the hover text show up when mouse is in a give column and not just on the bar itself. this hover text will show the data for all 3 colors and not just one.

thanks!

**EDIT:**

I got the hover text to show all 3 colors by writing a custom highlighter class

```
highlighter: {
show: true,
...
tooltipContentEditor:tooltipContentEditor,
}
...
function tooltipContentEditor(str, seriesIndex, pointIndex, plot) {
    var data1 = plot.data[2][pointIndex];
    var data2 = plot.data[1][pointIndex];
    var data3 = plot.data[0][pointIndex];
    var value = data1 + "-" + data2 + "-" + data3;
    return value;
}
```

of course this only works when you always have 3 colors for each bar, works for me so I'm using now. Now I need to figure out how to have the highlighter show easier for when the bar is too tiny.

**EDIT2:**

I figured out how to get the lighter to show.

1. create a dummy series, I set this to be the difference between a given column and the tallest column
2. change the color to rgb transparent, remove shadow, remove highlight and anything else.
3. in the hover over the invisible bar or any bar below it it will now show the full stats, yay!

Comment: Try to specify your yaxis as a log-axis : http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-logAxisRenderer-js.html

Comment: Have you tried using [breakpoints](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-linearAxisRenderer-js.html#$.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer.breakPoints)?

Answer (score 0):

The invisible data series sounds hackish, not to mention that now a user is getting inconsistent feedback when they put their mouse in this space, which will be a variable entity

This sounds like a great time to use to use a legend and then put a handler on the legend's items which triggers the hover for that relevant series

```
var $l = $('.jqplot-table-legend');
$l.on('mouseenter', function(e){
var $this = $(this),
    i = $this.index(),
    l = $l.length;
    // now call your custom highlight function or trigger the hover using relevant indices
})
.on('mouseleave', function(e){ 
    // hide visible tooltips
});
```

p.s. hover is deprecated please don't use it anymore